# How can I combine and get cdf of joint distribution of normal and beta distributions on the same set of data?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, joint-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

In my problem, I have a condition in which I need to compute the joint distribution of two dependent distributions. The first distribution is normal and the second one is beta distribution. How can I get the joint distribution function of these two distributions? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Actually, I am testing my hypothesis on the same data using both wilcox and ks tests. (As each of these tests captures one aspect of differences, and I have to detect both.) I need to somehow get one single statistic out of these two statistics (at the moment I am choosing minimum of these two but I know it is not correct). I searched a lot through published literature and found that the wilcox can be approximated using normal distribution and ks using beta distribution.
Now, I assume my case is:
P(A U B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A $\cap$ B)

where P(A) refers to probability obtained from normal distribution, P(B) refers to p-value from beta distribution.So what I need is the last part, to make this puzzle completed.

I hope this is clear more. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You appear to have reposted essentially the same question as here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608332/how-can-i-compute-the-joint-distribution-function-of-normal-distribution-and-bet#comment1129485_608332, which removes the context of previous comments and answers. If you need to clarify your question in some way, edit the original, rather than repost it. If you have an entirely new question (which would justify a new post), then it would need to be clearly different from the previous one

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608098/how-combine-two-statistics-from-different-tests ... you seem to be reasking more or less the same question repeatedly. Please don't do that.

Comment: There are multiple questions that relate to the difference between these two tests that may be of some help to you. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=wilcoxon+kolmogorov+smirnov

https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mann+whitney+kolmogorov+smirnov

Comment: @Glen_b The stack exchange suggested me to create a new post after I modified my original post.

Comment: That's interesting, since it seems to contradict the usual policy. Can you give more detail about what message you got?

Comment: @Glen_b *Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one.*

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to take the (already well established) problem with this phrasing up on meta.

Comment: However, even to follow the advice you got, you would need to actually clarify the question, rather than repost it almost as is.

Comment: @Glen_b I added the update part.

Comment: No, that update is entirely present in the previous one, so this post is superfluous, given that one. You have two copies of essentially the same post but that one has various comments which this one lacks.